# Bokeh on_change() method with Select() is not updating the plot

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I am trying to plot an interactive plot using Bokeh but default `on_change()` method is not working as the case is it only works on bokeh servers. In place of `on_change()` method what function can I use?
Below is the snippet of my code-

```
menu3 = Select(options=list(gap['Country'].unique()),value='India', title = 'Country')
source = ColumnDataSource(data=gap[gap['Country'] == 'India'])
p3=figure()
p3.circle(x='Year', y='fertility', color='green', source=source)
def callback(attr, old, new):
        new_value = menu3.value
        source = ColumnDataSource(data=gap[gap['Country'] == new_value])
        push_notebook()
menu3.on_change('value', callback)
layout3=column(menu3, p3)
show(layout3)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Interactive plots without the bokeh server can be obtained using JavaScript callbacks. Have a look at the examples here: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html